# Communicate with Kafka connectors

Tags: apache-kafka

I have to make a survey about the fellows Kafka connectors :

- Fivetran
- Tray.io
- TIBCO
- Azure Logic App
- Power Automate

I want to know if these tools communicate with Kafka using REST and / or native API?

Do these tools allow you to send and receive messages?

Comment: This isn't really a Kafka question. These are all vendor tools, you're better off asking them directly.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt i'm doing that but i can't reach a lot of them. I'm asking if there is someone who have any idea about one of these tools.

Comment: Asking about off-site resources is off-topic for Stackoverflow. To answer the last question, they probably use native Kafka TCP connections.